# pywinauto Wait and focus

Tags: python, wait, pywinauto

I'm trying to automate a windows application using pywinauto.
I can select the menu and open the "open file window".
I need to wait for this window to appear and then set focus to that window and click some buttons.

For some reason is not working.

```
def open_file():
    return pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(best_match=u'Open File', class_name='#32770')[0]
pywinauto.timings.WaitUntilPasses(20, 0.5,open_file)
print('wait for window')
open_file.SetFocus()
```

When I try to run this it says that open_file doesn't have a SetFocus option.

I'm a beginner in pywinauto and I'm pretty sure that this is something easy to fix but I don't know how :/

Comment: and btw, `def open_file():` has one **tab** less

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**open_file** is a function. It has no such method. It is much simpler to use **Application** object to wait dialog.

```
OpenDialog = pwa_app.window(best_match=u'Open', class_name='#32770').wait('visible', timeout=20, retry_interval=0.5)
OpenDialog.set_focus()
```

Low-level functions like **wait_until_passes** are already encapsulated inside **wait** and **wait_not** methods of class **WindowSpecification**.


Even more simple code should work:

```
pwa_app.OpenDialog.wait('visible', timeout=20)
pwa_app.OpenDialog.set_focus()
```

Comment: Did you check this code? As I could see in previous question, you don't call method `start_('your.exe')` or `connect_(path='exe_name')` for `Application` object. If you do that, many things will become simpler.